# Sending mail function in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

Current version I am using is:
Ruby = 1.8.7,  rails = 2.3.2

I wrote sending mails function. While I am running I got the below error"

> undefined method `default' for UserMailer:Class

my `UserMailer` class:-

```
default :from => "example@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = params[:user]
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(:to => "test123@gmail.com", :subject => "Test")
  end
end
```

How to solve this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `default' for UserMailer:Class

The method `default` as well as `mail` for the `ActionMailer` are **not introduced** in *Rails 2.3*, so you can't use them. The *Rails 2.3* syntax for your code would look like below

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = params[:user]
  @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
  recipients    "test123@gmail.com"
  from          "example@gmail.com"
  subject       "Test"
  sent_on       Time.now
  body          {:user => @user, :url => @url}
end
```

See [*Rails 2.3: Action Mailer Basics*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/action_mailer_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this without adding default

```
class WelcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user=user

     mail to: 'test123@gmail.com', subject: "test" ", from: 'example@gmail.com'
  end
end
```